# Как реализовать переход по Inline кнопкам с помощью call.data?

Tags: python, telebot

Обработчик клавиш "Выбрано кольцо " и "Выбрана цепочка" не работает, помогите исправить

```
import config
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data=='yes':
        markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        item_ring = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кольцо", callback_data='ring')
        item_chain = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Цепочка", callback_data="chain")
        markup_inline.add(item_ring, item_chain)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Какой вид украшения вы хотите заказать?", reply_markup=markup_inline)
    elif call.data=='no':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'До свидания!')
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def step(call):
    if call.data=="ring":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Выбрано кольцо")
    elif call.data=="chain":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Выбрана цепочка")
```

Answer (score 0):

Вторая функция никогда не запускается, потому что всегда срабатывает условие в первом декораторе `func=lambda call:True`.

Вам нужно изменить условия декораторов или переместить всю логику в одну функцию:

```python
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data=='yes':
        markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        item_ring = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кольцо", callback_data='ring')
        item_chain = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Цепочка", callback_data="chain")
        markup_inline.add(item_ring, item_chain)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Какой вид украшения вы хотите заказать?", reply_markup=markup_inline)
    elif call.data=='no':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'До свидания!')
    elif call.data=="ring":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Выбрано кольцо")
    elif call.data=="chain":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Выбрана цепочка")
```